# How can I get a BSD date command for Linux without compiling source code

Tags: linux, bsd, date-utility

I prefer the way the BSD date command allows returning arbitrary dates over the Linux date command.  Is there a date program using BSD command line syntax and functionality for Linux?

Comment: *arbitrary dates* - what do you mean? `man date` -> *`-d, --date=STRING`
              display time described by `STRING`, not `now`*

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.  Example: determine the last day of the previous month regardless of month or leap year.  For Linux a way is (know a better way?  Please post): date -d "$(date +%Y%m01) - 1 day".  With BSD, it's date -v1d -v-1d.  The BSD arguments are more obscure but straightforward.  A possible key difference may be that Linux doesn't allow multiple adjustments in one invocation (requiring the "$(date +%Y%m01) above) while "man date" on Mac (a BSD date program) says "The date can be adjusted as many times as required using these flags".